# Spring boot how to save when there's a foreign key on the entity?

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring

I'm new to Spring Boot and I would like to perform an insert operation but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. I've been following some guides, so please guide me in the right direction.

I'm using Mysql, and I have a "function" table with a foreign key mapped to the "servidor" table.

I would like to insert a new employee but I'm having problems with the foreign key (which refers to the function the employee has on the company). As far as I can understand, it's missing the foreign key so it complains about the column having no default value.

There's a one to many relationship between servidor and funcao.

```
package com.camaratapira.syspharma.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.camaratapira.syspharma.entity.Farmacia;
import com.camaratapira.syspharma.entity.Funcao;
import com.camaratapira.syspharma.entity.Servidor;
import com.camaratapira.syspharma.repositories.FuncaoRepository;
import com.camaratapira.syspharma.repositories.ServidorRepository;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ServidorController {
    
    @Autowired
    ServidorRepository servidorRepository;
    @Autowired
    FuncaoRepository funcaoRepository;
    EntityManager em;
    
    
    // lista todos os servidores
    @GetMapping("/servidor")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Servidor>> getAllServidors(@RequestParam(required=false)String nomeservidor){
        List<Servidor> servidor = new ArrayList<Servidor>();
        
        try {
            if(nomeservidor == null)
                servidorRepository.findAll().forEach(servidor::add);
            else
                servidorRepository.findBynomeservidor(nomeservidor).forEach(servidor::add);
            if(servidor.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(servidor, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            
        }
        
    }   
    
    @PostMapping("/inserirservidor")
    public ResponseEntity<Servidor> createServidor(@RequestBody Servidor servidor){
        try {
            Servidor _servidor = servidorRepository.save(new Servidor(servidor.getNomeservidor(), servidor.getCpf(), servidor.getRg(), servidor.getSalario(), servidor.isAtivo()));
            return new ResponseEntity<>(_servidor, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/atualizarservidor/{idservidor}")
    public ResponseEntity<Servidor> updateServidor(@PathVariable("idservidor") int idservidor, @RequestBody Servidor servidor){
        Optional<Servidor> servidorData = servidorRepository.findById(idservidor);
        if(servidorData.isPresent()){
            Servidor _servidor = servidorData.get();
            _servidor.setNomeservidor(servidor.getNomeservidor());
            _servidor.setCpf(servidor.getCpf());
            _servidor.setRg(servidor.getRg());
            _servidor.setSalario(servidor.getSalario());
            _servidor.setAtivo(servidor.isAtivo());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(servidorRepository.save(_servidor), HttpStatus.OK);         
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
                
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/deletarservidor/{idservidor}") /* é preciso adicionar a anotação @RequestBody para que ele possa achar o idservidor */
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deleteservidor(@PathVariable("idservidor") int idservidor, @RequestBody Servidor servidor){
        try {
            servidorRepository.deleteById(idservidor);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    } 
    
}
```

Entity servidor

```
package com.camaratapira.syspharma.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "servidor")
public class Servidor {
    
    public Servidor(){}
    
    public Servidor(String nomeservidor, String cpf, String rg, double salario, boolean ativo) {
        super();
        this.nomeservidor = nomeservidor;
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.rg = rg;
        this.salario = salario;
        this.ativo = ativo;
    }
    
    
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "idfuncao")
    private Funcao funcao; // necessário fazer os métodos getters e setters dessas funções para poderem retornar as 
    // chaves estrangeiras quando você fizer uma requisição GET, caso contrário, o sistema não vai saber onde procurar.
        
    public Funcao getFuncao() {
        return funcao;
    }

    public void setFuncao(Funcao funcao) {
        this.funcao = funcao;
    }

    public int getIdservidor() {
        return idservidor;
    }
    public void setIdservidor(int idservidor) {
        this.idservidor = idservidor;
    }
    public String getNomeservidor() {
        return nomeservidor;
    }
    public void setNomeservidor(String nomeservidor) {
        this.nomeservidor = nomeservidor;
    }
    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }
    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }
    public String getRg() {
        return rg;
    }
    public void setRg(String rg) {
        this.rg = rg;
    }
    public double getSalario() {
        return salario;
    }
    public void setSalario(double salario) {
        this.salario = salario;
    }
    public boolean isAtivo() {
        return ativo;
    }
    public void setAtivo(boolean ativo) {
        this.ativo = ativo;
    }
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "idservidor")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) // outras estratégias precisam de tabelas específicas no Banco de dados
    private int idservidor;
    
    @Column(name = "nomeservidor")
    private String nomeservidor;
    
    @Column(name = "cpf")
    private String cpf;
    
    @Column(name = "rg")
    private String rg;
    
    @Column(name = "salario")
    private double salario;
    
    @Column(name = "ativo")
    private boolean ativo;
    

    
}
```

Entity Function

```
package com.camaratapira.syspharma.entity;

import java.util.List;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "funcao")
public class Funcao {
    
    public Funcao() {}
    
    public Funcao(int idfuncao, String nomefuncao, int nivelvencimento) {
        this.idfuncao = idfuncao;
        this.nomefuncao = nomefuncao;
        this.nivelvencimento = nivelvencimento;
    }
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idfuncao;
    
    @Column(name = "nomefuncao")
    private String nomefuncao;
    @Column(name = "nivelvencimento")
    private int nivelvencimento;
        
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "idcargo")
    private Cargo idcargo;

    public Cargo getIdcargo() {
        return idcargo;
    }

    public void setIdcargo(Cargo idcargo) {
        this.idcargo = idcargo;
    }

    public int getIdfuncao() {
        return idfuncao;
    }
    public void setIdfuncao(int idfuncao) {
        this.idfuncao = idfuncao;
    }
    public String getNomefuncao() {
        return nomefuncao;
    }
    public void setNomefuncao(String nomefuncao) {
        this.nomefuncao = nomefuncao;
    }
    public int getNivelvencimento() {
        return nivelvencimento;
    }
    public void setNivelvencimento(int nivelvencimento) {
        this.nivelvencimento = nivelvencimento;
    }

    
}
```

When I do the post request, it complains that the column idfuncao cannot be null. How can I solve this? Thanks.

I tried wrapping the post request with the URL but that's not working, and I'm not sure how to write the post request on the controller in a way that includes the foreign key for funcao (idfuncao)

Comment: You have to create the parent before the child. Otherwise if the parent exists, you need to get its ID so that the child save will work, you cannot make it blank, otherwise that would be a parentless child

Comment: I was saving the employee wrong. I used save(servidor) and it worked just fine.